# Why does 1 billion * 100 == 1.2 billion?

Tags: c#, math

I have code that sets a default value of a cell to the value of the cell above multiplied by 100:

```
const int DUCKBILL_MULTIPLIER = 100;
. . .
cellValue = dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[args.RowIndex - 1].Cells[0].Value;
if (Convert.ToInt32(cellValue) > 0)
{
    int nextDefaultVal = Convert.ToInt32(cellValue) * DUCKBILL_MULTIPLIER;
    cellValue = nextDefaultVal;
}
prevVal = cellValue == null ? string.Empty : cellValue.ToString();
. . .
dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[args.RowIndex].Cells[args.ColumnIndex].Value = prevVal;
```

But once the value above gets to be 1000000000 (1 billion), the next value is 1215752192 (1,215,752,192 or approximately 1.2 billion) instead of 100 billion.

I understand that the max int value is 2,147,483,647 (approximately 2.1 billion); so why is the next value 1,215,752,192 instead of 2,147,483,647?

BTW, these vals are larger than the app will ever need to be, but I found this in testing "extreme" cases.

Comment: Integer Overflow... Integers don't saturate. They roll-over.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because multiple overflows are happening. Every time 2,147,483,647 is reached, the count starts over. Now, you have to keep in mind that it overflows to -2,147,483,648. So we have to take into account the whole Int32 range, which is 4,294,967,296 (it can be calculated from `(Int64)Int32.MaxValue + 1 - Int32.MinValue` or simply `2^32`.

The math:

```
(1 billion * 100) % (4,294,967,296) = 1215752192
```

Proof of concept in C# code:

```
var range = (Int64)Int32.MaxValue + 1 - Int32.MinValue;
Int64 val = 100000000000 % range;
Console.WriteLine(range);
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Comment: You mean `% 2,147,483,648`, because (1 billion * 100) % 2147483648 is 1215752192, which is the value reported in the question.

Comment: When the number overflows it will overflow to `-2,147,483,648`, not `0`.  You need to take the mod of `4294967296` (2^32), which still gives the same answer in this case.

Comment: @Servy You are right, I just updated the answer to be more accurate

Comment: @Adrian You could just get the value from `uint.MaxValue`

Comment: @Servy Actually, `uint.MaxValue` is 4,294,967,295, to which yuo'd have to add 1

Answer (score 5):

[(1,000,000,000 * 100) mod ((2,147,483,647 + 1) * 2) = 1,215,752,192](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2C000%2C000%2C000+%2a+100%29+mod+%28%282%2C147%2C483%2C647+%2B+1%29+%2a+2%29)

This is due to [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: Great, but you don't explain why this happens.

Comment: You mean "mod 2147483648": (1000000000 * 100) mod 2147483648 = 1215752192, which is the value reported in the question.

Comment: When the number overflows it will overflow to `-2,147,483,648`, not `0`.  You need to take the mod of `4294967296` (2^32), which still gives the same answer in this case.